# How do I make Hibernate custom types apply to aggregate functions?

Tags: java, hibernate, aggregate-functions

We're updating a Hibernate (3.6) application that defines a custom type for money, extending `org.hibernate.type.ImmutableType`. It's been fairly straightforward to make it instead extend `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType` and create a Java type descriptor to store `Money` as `BigInteger`.

However, various parts of the application use HQL queries that perform aggregate functions (usually SUM) on money fields. The old style, extending `ImmutableType`, automatically converted the result to `Money`, but with the new style, that's not happening; the result is a Long.

Does anyone know how to make Hibernate custom types automatically convert the result of aggregate functions?

Old user type:

```java
public class MoneyUserType extends ImmutableType {
   private final BigIntegerType bigIntegerType = new BigIntegerType();

   @Override
   public Object fromStringValue(final String string) {
      final BigInteger bigInteger = (BigInteger) bigIntegerType.fromStringValue(string);
      return Money.inCents(bigInteger);
   }

   @Override
   public Object get(final ResultSet rs, final String name) throws SQLException {
      final BigInteger bigInteger = (BigInteger) bigIntegerType.get(rs, name);
      if (null == bigInteger) {
         return null;
      }
      return Money.inCents(bigInteger);
   }

   @Override
   public void set(final PreparedStatement st, final Object object, final int index) throws SQLException {
      final Money money = (Money) object;
      bigIntegerType.set(st, money.getAmountInCents(), index);
   }

   @Override
   public int sqlType() {
      return bigIntegerType.sqlType();
   }

   @Override
   public String toString(final Object object) {
      final Money money = (Money) object;
      return bigIntegerType.toString(money.getAmountInCents());
   }

   public String getName() {
      return Money.class.getName();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public Class getReturnedClass() {
      return Money.class;
   }
}
```

New user type:

```java
public class MoneyUserType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Money> {
    
   public MoneyUserType() {
       super(BigIntTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, MoneyJavaTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
   }
    
   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return Money.class.getName();
   }
}
    
public class MoneyJavaTypeDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<Money> {
    
   public static final MoneyJavaTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new MoneyJavaTypeDescriptor();
    
   public MoneyJavaTypeDescriptor() {
      super(Money.class, ImmutableMutabilityPlan.INSTANCE);
   }
    
   @Override
   public Money fromString(final String string) {
      final BigInteger bigInteger = BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE.fromString(string);
       return Money.inCents(bigInteger);
   }
    
   @Override
   public <X> X unwrap(Money value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
      if (value == null) {
         return null;
      }
      if (type.isAssignableFrom(BigInteger.class)) {
         return (X) value.getAmountInCents();
      }
      if (type.isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
         return (X) Long.valueOf(value.getAmountInCents().longValue());
      }
      if (type.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
         return (X) Integer.valueOf(value.getAmountInCents().intValue());
      }
      throw unknownUnwrap(type);
   }
    
   @Override
   public <X> Money wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
      if (value == null) {
         return null;
      }
      if (Number.class.isInstance(value)) {
         return Money.inCents((Number) value);
      }
      throw unknownWrap(value.getClass());
   }
    
   @Override
   public String toString(final Money money) {
      return BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE.toString(money.getAmountInCents());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can work around this by adding extra setters on our DTOs and putting aliases in the queries as per [Custom type / converter in conjunction with Hibernate's Transformers.aliasToBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497294/custom-type-converter-in-conjunction-with-hibernates-transformers-aliastobean)

It's not ideal but it can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `INSTANCE` static field to your `MoneyUserType`:

```java
public class MoneyUserType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Money> {

   public static final MoneyUserType INSTANCE = new MoneyUserType();

   // ...
}
```

then add for example the following function to your custom hibernate dialect:

```java
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect
{
   public MyPostgreSQLDialect()
   {
      registerFunction("sum_money", new StandardSQLFunction("sum", MoneyUserType.INSTANCE));
   }
}
```

declare this dialect in your `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`

and then you will be able to use the `sum_money` function in your hql:

```java
Money sum = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select sum_money(m.money) from MoneyEntity m",
     Money.class
).getSingleResult();
```